# Is a global variable for a Twig template available inside a Symfony2 controller?

Tags: symfony, global-variables, twig

A **global variable** for a *Twig template* can be defined inside the **config.yml** of a *Symfony2* application as in the following:

```
twig:                 
    globals:
      var_name: var_value
```

Hence, in each Twig template the variable can be used as follows:

```
{{var_name}}
```

that will display

```
var_value
```

*Do you know such a way to get the value of a global variable just inside a Symfony2 controller?*

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to grab a particular value. But you can get the full array of globals from the twig service and then grab it's offset.

```
$twig = $this->container->get('twig');
$globals = $twig->getGlobals();
echo $globals['var_name'];
```

Comment: In symfony 4.4 you get a warning when doing this: "Method 'getGlobals' is marked as @internal"

Answer (score 4):

The right practice is to follow the official tutorial about Twig global variables in the [Symfony's Cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/templating/global_variables.html). In practice, one should define a global variable that can be used in the controllers, e.g.:

```
  ; app/config/parameters.ini
  [parameters]
     my_global_var: HiAll
```

Then the variable is defined as global for the Twig templates

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    globals:
        my_var: %my_global_var%
```

Hence, `{{my_var}}` will return *HiAll* but one should take care of the value once in the `parameters.ini` file.

So, the answer to the question is no! Or precisely, not in an effective way. MDrollette drawn a possible way!

Comment: I'm more for this solution as it also allows to inject the param into container aware classes. The parameter can still be defined directly into config.yml though

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't clear if you wanted to access the twig var in the controller, or just access a global var from the config. Here is how to access a global var from the config file...

You can place the value in the parameters section of the config..

```
parameters:
    var_name: some_value
```

Now you can access it from the controller...

```
$value = $this->container->getParameter('var_name');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The question is related to the global variables defined for Twig templates! Can they be accessed also within a Controller or they can only be used in Twig templates?

Comment: The [Symfony official guide](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/global_variables.html) states that the _parameters.ini_ file can be used, but doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd better to use bundle configuration or DIC parameters for your value, and then add it to the twig globals (via your bundle extension class, for example), and not trying to do the opposite.

Comment: So, is the answer "No, is not possible"?